# Android sentIntent of smsManager.sendTextMessage makes UI refresh

Tags: android, user-interface, smsmanager

Did anyone had this problem before or can someone explain me what's happening?

**Code description:**
Following code takes some information from my object ContactFromXML and sends some textmessages where it needs to.

**Code:**

```
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0); 
        for (int i=0; i<contactsCount;i++){
            while(contactsIt.hasNext()){
                ContactFromXML contact = contactsIt.next();
                if (mTeam.equals(contact.mTeam)){
                    smsMessage = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.mess_sms_message), contact.mVoornaam, mTimeOfArrival);
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact.mTel, null, smsMessage, pi , null);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Problem:**
For every textmessage that my code sends, it sort of refreshes the UI. First I tought it would be because the messages where sent from my UI thread, so I've put it into a AsyncTask. But that didn't solve anything. After some testing, I found out that it was because of de SentItent 'pi'. If I don't you use one, it gives no problem.

**Question:**
Can anyone explain this? I would really like to use the feature to see if a text message was actually sent, without that users notice a UI refresh.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `PendingIntent`?

Comment: The PendingIntent is set in the sendTextMessage as a sentIntent. Later in my code I'm going to put a listener on it to make sure the textmessage was actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), the `sentIntent` which is a `PendingIntent` is sent `when the message is successfully sent, or failed.` Here you are setting an activity in the `PendingIntent`, so whenever your message is `sent` or `failed` to be sent, your `PendinfIntent` is activated, and that refreshes your activity.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Anyone has an idea how to overcome the refresh or bypass it while still using the sentIntent?

Comment: use `PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sent, 0)` where `sent` is `Intent sent = new Intent("SMS_SENT")`

Comment: and use a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the broadcast